# How to remove the filteredvalue from the kendogrid search box?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid which implements filters. One of the column is location. The location column is bound to country. I can filter the grid by typing the country name in the location filter box and it filters.But if I send a list of countries to the kendogrid. It filters the grid based on the list of the countries, but the only problem is that the boxfilter only shows the first country from the list. How do I remove that, or maybe show all of the countries in the searchbox for the location.

Here is a picture

[image]

Here I am passing a list of countries to filter the grid but it only shows US because it is the first in the list. The filtered results is fine but the only searchbox value is misleading. How do I fix this?

Comment: So instead of a textbox as the filter, you are wanting a dropdownlist as filter? The dropdownlist would contain the list you pass it. Take a look at [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization) from Telerik and see how the "City" filter is set.

Comment: Is there any way to not show the text in the textbox filter when there is more than one locations to be filtered? I need the textbox filter, so it is typeable.